# A minha função setInterval não está a funcionar como pretendido

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

Eis o código:

```js
//Função para contar os segudos
function conta_seg(){
 sec++;
 if (sec < 10 && min == 0) {
  document.getElementById("conta-tempo").innerHTML = "00:0" + sec;
 }else if (sec < 60 && min == 0) {
  document.getElementById("conta-tempo").innerHTML = "00" + sec;
 }else{
  sec %= 60;
  min++;
  if (min < 10 && sec < 10) {
   document.getElementById("conta-tempo").innerHTML = "0" + min + ":0" + sec;
  }else if (min < 10 && sec <60) {
   document.getElementById("conta-tempo").innerHTML = "0" + min + ":" + sec;
  }else if (min < 60 && sec < 10) {
   document.getElementById("conta-tempo").innerHTML = min + ":0" + sec;
  }else if (min < 60 && sec < 60) {
   document.getElementById("conta-tempo").innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;
  }
 }
}

var clock = setInterval(conta_seg(), 1000);
```

Verifiquei qual o erro com console.log e deu que alguma coisa estava undefined. O que posso fazer para resolver o problema e o programa contar os segundos normalmente?

Comment: Inês, você está utilizando as variáveis `sec` e `min`, porém no seu código aparentemente elas não foram declaradas em lugar nenhum. Tente declará-las, que isso deve resolver seu problema.

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque o código de erro retornado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Além de não ter declarado as variáveis `sec` e `min`, a chamada da função no `setInterval` está errada:

```
setInterval(conta_seg(), 1000);
                     ↑↑
```

Quando você coloca os parênteses, você está executando a função diretamente (e só uma vez) e não fazendo dela uma função a ser executada a cada volta do `setInterval`.

O correto é referenciar a função externa (sem os parênteses):

```
setInterval(conta_seg, 1000);
```

Reproduzi o código com essas correções e está funcionando (veja abaixo), porém acredito que haja outros problemas de lógica/programação, pois após o relógio atingir 1 minuto, o resultado começa a ficar estranho. Veja:

```js
//Função para contar os segudos
var sec = 0, min = 0;

function conta_seg(){
 sec++;
 if (sec < 10 && min == 0) {
  document.getElementById("conta-tempo").innerHTML = "00:0" + sec;
 }else if (sec < 60 && min == 0) {
  document.getElementById("conta-tempo").innerHTML = "00" + sec;
 }else{
  sec %= 60;
  min++;
  if (min < 10 && sec < 10) {
   document.getElementById("conta-tempo").innerHTML = "0" + min + ":0" + sec;
  }else if (min < 10 && sec <60) {
   document.getElementById("conta-tempo").innerHTML = "0" + min + ":" + sec;
  }else if (min < 60 && sec < 10) {
   document.getElementById("conta-tempo").innerHTML = min + ":0" + sec;
  }else if (min < 60 && sec < 60) {
   document.getElementById("conta-tempo").innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;
  }
 }
}

var clock = setInterval(conta_seg, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="conta-tempo"></div>
```